# Applying a VCL style to TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

Is there any way to apply a VCL style to TWebBrowser? I would like to change the scrollbars to fit my selected style.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only disable Windows Themes to classic style using [`DOCHOSTUIFLAG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag `DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NOTHEME`. If you extend [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8579489/960757) example and to the `GetHostInfo` method add the code `pInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TDocHostUIInfo); pInfo.dwFlags := $00080000; Result := S_OK;` you will get classic Windows theme in your web browser control. But I know, that's what you (or anyone else) won't :) +1 here

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284003/delphi-xe2-vcl-style-and-webbrowser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TWebBrowser is a thin wrapper around the Internet Explorer ActiveX client. All of the UI behavior is controlled by IE, not the VCL. So I don't think you can control the look with VCL styles. You will have to use HTML/CSS styles instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, it's possible apply a vcl style to the scrollbar of a TWebBrowser, check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284003/delphi-xe2-vcl-style-and-webbrowser http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/delphi-vcl-styles-and-twebbrowser-source-code-released/