# How do I redirect the TWebBrowser control to a custom URL?

Tags: delphi, url, redirect, iwebbrowser2, twebbrowser

Example:

1. I navigate to [`http://www.stackoverflow.com`](http://www.stackoverflow.com) with my web browser control
2. there's a link to FAQ in the top bar, with target [`https://stackoverflow.com/faq`](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)
3. I need to redirect e.g. to the [`http://math.stackexchange.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/about) when I click the FAQ link

Comment: I've posted this just for sharing. It might be useful e.g. when you are using the [`TWebBrowser`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) control in your application and you want to keep users on your web portal, as a parental control etc.

Comment: This site is for Q&A, not posting factoids.

Comment: Please take it as a [question and answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) ;) And hey, it's easy, just vote down or vote to close and I'll delete it from here ;)

Comment: @MarcB This is a superb Q&A. That the asker answered it is irrelevant. It contains extremely useful and valuable information. I comment this as an exemplary post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way, as [`kobik`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937125/kobik) suggested is to use [`TWebBrowser.OnBeforeNavigate2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnBeforeNavigate2) event. Here is the example.

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  if URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/faq' then
  begin
    // setting this flag to True will cancel the current navigation
    Cancel := True;

    // changing this declared parameter doesn't affect anything
    // I've used it just because it's already declared
    URL := 'http://math.stackexchange.com';

    // interrupt all pending navigations and stop dynamic page elements
    (pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Stop;

    // and navigate to the target URL
    (pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Navigate2(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers);
  end;
end;
```

There's another, more complicated method how to achieve the same. It's about using the [`IDocHostUIHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. Except the control of the menus and toolbars visibility, context menu configuration and some events it provides, let's say, the redirect capability.

To be more specific, it's the [`IDocHostUIHandler.TranslateUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. This method enables the host to modify the URL to be loaded. It exposes the input URL where the web browser control is going to navigate and the output URL where you redirect it, if you want.

The following example shows the implementation of the [`IDocHostUIHandler.TranslateUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. Please note that I've used the interposed class so if you put this code into your unit, only those web browsers on the form or those created in this unit dynamically will get this behavior.

If you click on the Button1 you'll be navigated to the [`http://www.stackoverflow.com`](http://www.stackoverflow.com) and if you click on the FAQ link which is directed to the [`https://stackoverflow.com/faq`](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) you'll be redirected to the [`http://math.stackexchange.com`](http://math.stackexchange.com).

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, SHDocVw, ActiveX, StdCtrls, OleCtrls;

type
  PDocHostUIInfo = ^TDocHostUIInfo;
  TDocHostUIInfo = record
    cbSize: ULONG;
    dwFlags: DWORD;
    dwDoubleClick: DWORD;
end;

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IDocHostUIHandler
// Flags:     (0)
// GUID:      {BD3F23C0-D43E-11CF-893B-00AA00BDCE1A}
// *********************************************************************//
  IDocHostUIHandler = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{BD3F23C0-D43E-11CF-893B-00AA00BDCE1A}']
    function ShowContextMenu(const dwID: DWORD; const ppt: PPoint;
      const pcmdtReserved: IUnknown; const pdispReserved: IDispatch): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDocHostUIInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ShowUI(const dwID: DWORD; const pActiveObject: IOleInPlaceActiveObject;
      const pCommandTarget: IOleCommandTarget; const pFrame: IOleInPlaceFrame;
      const pDoc: IOleInPlaceUIWindow): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function HideUI: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function UpdateUI: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function EnableModeless(const fEnable: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnDocWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnFrameWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ResizeBorder(const prcBorder: PRect; const pUIWindow: IOleInPlaceUIWindow;
      const fRameWindow: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function TranslateAccelerator(const lpMsg: PMSG; const pguidCmdGroup: PGUID;
      const nCmdID: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetOptionKeyPath(var pchKey: POleStr; const dw: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDropTarget(const pDropTarget: IDropTarget; out ppDropTarget: IDropTarget): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetExternal(out ppDispatch: IDispatch): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function TranslateUrl(const dwTranslate: DWORD; const pchURLIn: POleStr; var ppchURLOut: POleStr): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function FilterDataObject(const pDO: IDataObject; out ppDORet: IDataObject): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  TWebBrowser = class(SHDocVw.TWebBrowser, IDocHostUIHandler)
  private
    function ShowContextMenu(const dwID: DWORD; const ppt: PPoint;
      const pcmdtReserved: IUnknown; const pdispReserved: IDispatch): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDocHostUIInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ShowUI(const dwID: DWORD; const pActiveObject: IOleInPlaceActiveObject;
      const pCommandTarget: IOleCommandTarget; const pFrame: IOleInPlaceFrame;
      const pDoc: IOleInPlaceUIWindow): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function HideUI: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function UpdateUI: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function EnableModeless(const fEnable: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnDocWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnFrameWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ResizeBorder(const prcBorder: PRect; const pUIWindow: IOleInPlaceUIWindow;
      const fRameWindow: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function TranslateAccelerator(const lpMsg: PMSG; const pguidCmdGroup: PGUID;
      const nCmdID: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetOptionKeyPath(var pchKey: POleStr; const dw: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDropTarget(const pDropTarget: IDropTarget; out ppDropTarget: IDropTarget): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetExternal(out ppDispatch: IDispatch): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function TranslateUrl(const dwTranslate: DWORD; const pchURLIn: POleStr; var ppchURLOut: POleStr): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function FilterDataObject(const pDO: IDataObject; out ppDORet: IDataObject): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TWebBrowser.ShowContextMenu(const dwID: DWORD; const ppt: PPoint;
  const pcmdtReserved: IUnknown; const pdispReserved: IDispatch): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDocHostUIInfo): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.ShowUI(const dwID: DWORD; const pActiveObject: IOleInPlaceActiveObject;
  const pCommandTarget: IOleCommandTarget; const pFrame: IOleInPlaceFrame;
  const pDoc: IOleInPlaceUIWindow): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.HideUI: HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.UpdateUI: HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.EnableModeless(const fEnable: BOOL): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.OnDocWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.OnFrameWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.ResizeBorder(const prcBorder: PRect;
  const pUIWindow: IOleInPlaceUIWindow; const fRameWindow: BOOL): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.TranslateAccelerator(const lpMsg: PMSG;
  const pguidCmdGroup: PGUID; const nCmdID: DWORD): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.GetOptionKeyPath(var pchKey: POleStr; const dw: DWORD): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.GetDropTarget(const pDropTarget: IDropTarget;
  out ppDropTarget: IDropTarget): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.GetExternal(out ppDispatch: IDispatch): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

function TWebBrowser.TranslateUrl(const dwTranslate: DWORD;
  const pchURLIn: POleStr; var ppchURLOut: POleStr): HRESULT;
begin
  // pchURLIn is the URL where the browser is going to navigate
  // ppchURLOut is the URL where the browser will navigate

  if pchURLIn = 'https://stackoverflow.com/faq' then
    ppchURLOut := 'http://math.stackexchange.com';

  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TWebBrowser.FilterDataObject(const pDO: IDataObject;
  out ppDORet: IDataObject): HRESULT;
begin
  Result := E_NOTIMPL;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
end;

end.
```

Comment: +1. btw, no need to re-declare TWebBrowser. just use document.SetUIHandler with a new instance of IDocHostUIHandler. also redirection can simply be done on: `OnBeforeNavigate2`

Comment: @kobik, thanks. I forgot about `OnBeforeNavigate` and never heard about `SetUIHandler`, good to know it. So in this case this Q&A losing its sense, because it would be quite overkill to implement it this heavy weight, so deleting ... :)

Comment: Ok, so let me add your comment to the first place as the easier solution and the rest from me as an alternative :)

Comment: note that `OnBeforeNavigate2` a bit tricky: you can't simply return URL to navigate. you need to set `Cancel := True` and then use `WebBrowser1.Navigate2` with parameters passed by the event handler. so your method is a nice alternative. `SetUIHandler` is casted to document via `ICustomDoc`.

Comment: @kobik, thanks, I'm playing with this now. I knew there is `OnBeforeNavigate2` but I never used it. As they say in the [`reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768280%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) you should also call [`IWebBrowser2.Stop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before you [`navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752134%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: note that I mainly use `IDocHostUIHandler` to disable the IE context menu. this is done by returning result of `S_OK` in `ShowContextMenu`.

Comment: @TLama Why not use URLMon and IInternetProtocol?

Comment: Good to know: When EditorMode is On, the WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2 will not be executed.