# TWebBrowser - How to detect which tag was clicked?

Tags: html, delphi, onclick, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

How to detect which HTML element (tag) was clicked in TWebBrowser when DesignMode is ON?

**The problem:**
When DesignMode is on:

- Document_OnMouseOver never executes.
- The document never completes loading.
- BeforeNavigate2 is not called when I click a link.

Update:
The thing that I need is IHTMLTxtRange (I think). It works when I double click a link/word. But I don't know how to get the tag under caret when no text/link is selected.

```
procedure TForm1.getRange;
var
  Sel: IHTMLSelectionObject;
  Range: IHTMLTxtRange;
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
begin
    Doc := EmbeddedWB.Doc2;
    if Assigned(Doc) then
    begin
      Sel := Doc.selection;
      if Assigned(Sel) then
      begin
        if (Sel.type_ = 'None') or (Sel.type_ = 'Text') then
        begin
          Range := Sel.createRange as IHTMLTxtRange;
          Range.expand('word');

          Memo.Text:=
              Range.htmlText + crlf +    // full tag
              Range.text;                // only text
        end;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think that the active element is what you want. Surely you need to get the coordinates (client coordinates), and call `IHtmlDocument2.elementFromPoint`.

Comment: you can get the link in OnBeforeNavigate event

Comment: Hi David. I already tried that yesterday but with no luck. I only get 'BODY'. Here is the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110608/twebbrowser-detecting-the-tag-under-cursor-on-click

Comment: Just consume the event? Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8579489/800214) for a nice example and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768326(v=vs.85).aspx) for the official documentation.

Comment: @DarkPresidentOfAmerica: does this help you or not?

Comment: @whosrdaddy-Nope. That won't help because I have DesignMode = ON so the BeforeNavigate2 won't be called when I click a (any) link. Any other ideas?

Comment: @whosrdaddy-The thing that I need is IHTMLTxtRange (I think). It works when I double click a link/word. But I don't know how to get the tag under caret when no text/link is selected.

Answer (score 1):

This is example how to use mouse coordenates to get the element that was clicked in webbrowser!

```
 var
  X, Y: Integer;
  document,E: OleVariant;
begin
  if (Msg.message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) and IsDialogMessage(WebBrowser1.Handle, Msg) then
  begin
    X := LOWORD(Msg.lParam);
    Y := HIWORD(Msg.lParam);
    document := WebBrowser1.Document;
    E := document.elementFromPoint(X, Y);
   Edit1.Text := 'You clicked on:' + E.outerHTML;
  end;
  Handled := False;
end;
```