# TWebBrowser - Detecting the tag under caret

Tags: html, delphi, internet-explorer, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

I want to detect on which HTML tag (more exactly hyperlink) is the caret.

```
procedure THTMLEdit.ShowTag;     
var
  CursorPos: TPoint;
  HtmlElement: IHTMLElement;
  iHTMLDoc: IHtmlDocument2;
begin
 if Supports(wbBrowser.Document, IHtmlDocument2, iHTMLDoc) then
  begin
    if GetcaretPos(CursorPos) then
    begin
      CursorPos := wbBrowser.screentoclient(CursorPos);
      HtmlElement := iHTMLDoc.ElementFromPoint(CursorPos.X, CursorPos.Y);  // I NEED KEYBOARD CARET HERE, NOT MOUSE CURSOR
      if HtmlElement <> NIL
      then label1.Caption:= HtmlElement.tagName;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Notes:
TWebBrowser is in DesignMode ( DesignMode := 'On' ).
TWebBrowser is in its own form at design time but at runtime is re-parented in another form (in a panel).

UPDATE:
The thing that I need is IHTMLTxtRange (I think). It works when I double click a link/word. But I don't know how to get the tag under caret when no text/link is selected.

Comment: You might take a look at my answer to this q:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527367/detect-when-the-active-element-in-a-twebbrowser-document-changes, in particular `TForm1.AnEvent`

Comment: It's very hard to help you with such vague information. You want the tag under the cursor? But you call `GetCaretPos`. Do you want cursor or caret? And in your other question you are apparently interested only in `<a>` links. Can you slow down, take some time, and tell us what you are actually doing. Spamming us with a series of imprecise and unclear questions is not constructive, and is indicative of the muddled thinking that is holding you back.

Comment: [Usually] when you click an editor you will have the cursor and caret in the same place. But you are right, I was ambiguous. I want the tag under the caret.

Comment: @DarkPresidentOfAmerica, you can handle the the `onmouseup` event with MartynA's answer. then something like: `rg:=Doc.selection.createRange; rg.collapse; el:=rg.parentElement;`

Comment: in what event you call ShowTag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetcaretPos(CursorPos) returns client (relative) coordinates (See [GetCaretPos function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648402(v=vs.85).aspx))

Remove wbBrowser.screentoclient(CursorPos) and it should work fine. I have tested with your code sample above

Comment: It ALMOST works. The problem: It shows the *previous* clicked tag. For example if I click a <P> tag and then i click a link (<a href>) it will show <p>. So, in order to work, I have to click the link twice!